# Undergrad-Total Institutional Aid Received by school

Tags: data-request, education, aid

Is there a data set out there that has OPEID with types and total aid received, specifically, Total Institutional Aid (if there others or all included, that's definitely ok)?

I've tried following the steps outlined on page three of this document: https://nces.ed.gov/pubs2015/2015604.pdf but I can't seem to get dollar totals.